# Opciones para enviar un Arreglo desde una vista a un Controlador Laravel

Tags: laravel, array, controller, rutas, vistas

Buenas me pueden ayudar con este problema?

Sucede que tengo un controlador que carga datos de cientos de usuarios en una matriz y los manda a una vista.

Luego en la vista se muestran todos los datos en una tabla. ACA ESTA EL PROBLEMA.

En esta vista el usuario verifica que los datos esten bien y tiene la opcion de Exportar las tablas en Excel. Tengo que mandar toda la matriz desde la vista al metodo que me genera el archivo excel.

Hay alguna forma de pasar un arreglo a un metodo desde una vista?

Yo hasta ahora lo solucione convirtiendo la matriz en una String pero parece que la String es demaciado larga para ser enviada por la ruta al metodo generador, por que al seleccionar una cantidad X de usuarios para mostrar la ruta al metodo no responde, devuelve NOT FOUND, entonces vuelvo a pedir porfavor.

Alguien conoce la forma de enviar toda la matriz desde la vista al metodo generador del Excel?

O tal vez lo correcto seria enviar los parametros de la consulta a BD inicial y volver a hacer la consulta a BD en el metodo generador del Excel?

Comment: Es una mejor opción lo segundo, incluso podrían almacenarse en sesión dichos parámetros.

Comment: muchas gracias, hare lo q dices

Answer (score -1, accepted):

se puede modificar el limite de las variables GET o POST, pero no seria la mejor opción en lo que a mi respecta.

Por lo que entiendo, el usuario no altera los datos, simplemente los verifica. Entonces, lo que se puede hacer es una variable de sesión, por ejemplo: `\Session::put('datos_verificados',false)`. Y cuando el valor "true", le permitirá crear la planilla de excel con todos los datos.

Otra solución puede ser un formulario HTML:

```
<form action="{{route('exportar.excel')}}">
  @crsf
 <input type="hidden" name="tabla" value="nombre_de_la_tabla" />
 <input type="radio" value="1" name="datos_verificados" /> Datos OK <br/>
 <input type="radio" value="0" name="datos_verificados" /> Rechazar <br/>
 <button type="submit">Enviar</button>
</form>
```

De esta manera podes verificar si los datos de esa tabla son correctos desde el controlador.

Si no te respondí correctamente te pido que me brindes más información así puede entender.

Comment: Esta pregunta se basa en opiniones y no debería ser respondida.